# button click open component

Tags: angular, typescript

In the project I work with Angular, I want it to go to the other component when the button is clicked, but it does not. I connected the navigate method to the button in the menu and wrote the method but it didn't. How can I fix?

.html

```
<button mat-menu-item (click)="navigate()">Reservations List</button>
```

.ts

```
navigate() {
    this.router.navigate(['reservationdetail']);
}
```

.routing

```
  { path: 'reservationdetail', component: ReservationdetailComponent }
```

.app module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HotelComponent } from './hotel/hotel.component';
import { ReservationdetailComponent } from ' 
./reservationdetail/reservationdetail.component'; 
import { RezervasyonComponent } from './rezervasyon/rezervasyon.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'hotel', component: HotelComponent },
{ path: "**", redirectTo: "hotel", pathMatch: "full" },
{ path: 'rezervazyon', component: RezervasyonComponent },
{ path: 'reservationdetail', component: ReservationdetailComponent }
];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: You need router-outlet to render the dynamically routed component https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet

Comment: Check your browser console for any errors - this may be helpful. Or post more of your code here

Comment: I'm not getting an error. I edited the code in more detail. I applied it to the bottom, and I got the Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'button' error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have this route setup in app.module.ts at root level?

if not, you must be having other modules route before your component.

you make sure you write it like,

```
this.router.navigate(['/root/parent/../reservationdetail']);
```

that will work

**UPDATE**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'hotel', component: HotelComponent },
{ path: 'rezervazyon', component: RezervasyonComponent },
{ path: 'reservationdetail', component: ReservationdetailComponent },
{ path: "**", redirectTo: "hotel" }
];
```

can you update like this?

Comment: I edited the code and shared it. I installed the app module up. This method does not work unfortunately

Comment: can you tell me hierarchical structure of your app from root to this component. I am asking this because it is usually easy to achieve.

Comment: I am writing a hotel project. There is a button when my page first opened. Clicking the button, two options appear. The first option is the section where the search screen works properly, but the second option should go to the reservation detail page, but I could not do it.

Comment: I guess that's the catch, you must be having some sort of path for first page, can you check that. is 1st page opening at localhost:4200

Comment: hotel component opens on the first page. Because I wrote it as root, you can look at the code above.

Comment: Can you move the wildcard route entry to the end of array and try?

Comment: @john did you try it?

Comment: sorry I don't understand

Comment: Also @john can you please upvote and accept my answer if my answer helps you, I am kinda trying to build the reputation on Stack overflow, so small favor 

Comment: I tried but it didn't work thanks, I'll find another way now

Comment: can you tell me console errors or warnings if any, I might be able to help you

Comment: Not error but not work. [routerLink] = "['/ reservation detail']" was written above but I tried it but it didn't work

Comment: Not sure, what the problem is then. just to be sure, make sure you did the changes I suggested. that should help. also remember not too use  "**" path untill the end of routes array. peace .

Answer (score 3):

If only navigate in function u don't to navigate in function . U can navigate from html

```
<button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="['/reservationdetail']">Reservations List</button>
```

Comment: hocam yardımın için teşekkürler ama şöyle bir hata aldım onu çözmeye çalışıyorum şimdi. Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'button'. ("u">
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="search2()">Price Search</button>
    <button mat-menu-item [ERROR ->][routerLink]="['/reservationdetail']">Reservations List</button>
</mat-menu>

Comment: App.modules içine routermodülü import ettin mi? import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

Comment: evet onu çok önceden yaptım zaten başka route işlemleri için hatta şimdi de baktım yapmışım zaten.

Comment: App.modules de soru içinde paylaşır mısın?

Comment: Posts and comments should be [in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange).

Comment: Editledim hocam

Comment: Sorry @ConnorsFan I just wanted him to share app.module.

Comment: @john Did u create also module for your this page's component. If yes, u also need to configure your routings in that module too.

Comment: I mean if u have rezervasyon-module.ts in your project , u need to configure there too.

Comment: I did not create another module. There is only this.

Comment: Can u try this `<button mat-menu-item routerLink="reservationdetail">Reservations List</button>`

Comment: I marked the correct option, thanks for the feedback